# F# draw geometric object

Tags: object, f#, draw

I have to create 3 functions. One that draw a rectangle, the other one a triangle an the last one a house like on the picture below.

```
type RoboInstruction = | F | L | R

type RoboProgram =
    | Forward
    | Left
    | Right
    | Seq of RoboProgram * RoboProgram
    | Repeat of Nat * RoboProgram

let rectangle: RoboProgram = (....)
let triangle: RoboProgram = (....)
let nikolaus: RoboProgram = (....)
```

I tried to draw the rectangle with the following code but it doesn't work I don't know why:

```
let rectangle: RoboProgram =
  Repeat(2,
    Repeat(3N, Forward);
    Repeat(90N, Left);
    Repeat(2N, Forward);
    Repeat(90N, Left))
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: `Fehlermeldung:
 Test method Tests+Tests.compile rechteck threw exception:
System.Exception: TODO
Stapelverfolgung:
    at Program.compile(RoboProgram program) in C:\Users\Alessandro\Documents\Uni-KL\GrundlagenderProgrammierung\Übungen\Aufgabe-06-3\Program.fs:line 31
   at Tests.Tests.compile rechteck() in C:\Users\Alessandro\Documents\Uni-KL\GrundlagenderProgrammierung\Übungen\Aufgabe-06-3\Tests.fs:line 22`

Comment: From what I see you do not have access to an IDE that can give you  error messages as you type when the syntax is wrong. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Seq` command uses tuples that only let you pair two instructions at a time you would need to nest several `Seq`s to be able to hold 4 instructions together.

(I switched from `Nat` to `int` just because `Nat` requires me to load an extra library.)

Your could do it like this:

```
let rectangle: RoboProgram =
    Repeat(2,
        Seq(
            Seq(Repeat( 3, Forward)
              , Repeat(90, Left   ))
          , Seq(Repeat( 2, Forward)
              , Repeat(90, Left   ))
        )
    )
```

Or like this:

```
let rectangle: RoboProgram =
    Repeat(2,
        Seq(Repeat( 3, Forward)
      , Seq(Repeat(90, Left   )
      , Seq(Repeat( 2, Forward)
      ,     Repeat(90, Left   )
        )))
    )
```

This second style is typical of the bind functions from functional programming. In fact in F# you could create a Computation Expression to do this:

```
type RoboBuilder() = // Computation Expression builder
    member __.ReturnFrom x = x
    member __.Bind(x, f) = Seq(x, f x)

let robo = RoboBuilder()
```

that would let you generate that same code like this:

```
let rectangle3 =
    Repeat(2, robo {
        let! _ = Repeat( 3, Forward)
        let! _ = Repeat(90, Left   )
        let! _ = Repeat( 2, Forward)
        return!  Repeat(90, Left   )
    })
```

If this last part is not clear do not worry, it is an advanced feature of F#.

Comment: Your code seems to work, but the problem is I forgot to write that I can't modify my code I have to write a code with the function that is given to me

Comment: What library is Nat from?

Comment: Actually, I do not know I assume is a library for natural numbers somewhere. Possibly one created for this specific course.